# Cant set width element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jquery:
`$(".mce-content-body p")`

and return 
`<p>"text"</p>`

But i cant use: `$(".mce-content-body p").width(300)` will rerturn `VM9281:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null at <anonymous>:1:39`

How i set witdh for all

in idv

Comment: Code shown [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/t4x5ue2x/). Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 1):

Wrong Syntax.Try,

```
$(".mce-content-body p").css("width","300px");
```

**Note:** The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

Thanks !

Comment: You are quoting the wrong part of the documentation. Setting using `width(300)` does exact same thing. Read the rest of the documentation. `If no explicit unit is specified (like "em" or "%") then "px" is assumed.`

Answer (score -3):

You need to set it as a CSS property in jQuery.

HTML tag should be set like

```
<p class="mce-content-body"> text <p>
```

jQuery

```
$(".mce-content-body").css("width","12px");
```

Comment: whats wrong with the way op is setting it?

Comment: There are syntax error in you solution. and more on to that It doesn't seems to solve OP's problem.